# rename of related list section of custom link on page layout of case

Tags: page-layout

in case page-layout there is a section which name is custom link

[image]

[image]

when i go to this section there is section name field which is readonly I want to rename how can i edit this name and put "enutzerdefinierte Links" instead of custom links(its a 3 column section)

Comment: You should check translation​ workbench, I don't think you can rename it from layout.

Comment: Translation also don't showing custom link, i already checked

Comment: Looks like a bug, the section name is no read only for me. But even if I change it or override it from translation workbench, Its not changing.  For translation navigate to Translate under Translation Workbench, In Setup Component choose Layout Section, then choose your Object and expand the appropriate layout, you should be able to see the Custom Links.

Comment: @RahulSharma i already done this step no custom link found